# How to prove the validity of a FOL formula using resolution?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

So, I have to prove the validity of the following formula:

F = ∃x[(P(x) → P(a)) ∧ (P(x) → P(b))]

To do this, using resolution, should I negate my F and then if I can get a resolvent that is the empty set this will prove that the negation of F is unsatisfiable meaning that F is valid?

Update:

Negate F:

¬∃x[(P(x) → P(a)) ∧ (P(x) → P(b))]

∀x¬[(P(x) → P(a)) ∧ (P(x) → P(b))]

Get rid of implications:

∀x¬[(¬P(x) ∨ P(a)) ∧ (¬P(x) ∨ P(b))]

Import negation:

∀x[(P(x) ∧ ¬P(a)) ∨ (P(x) ∧ ¬P(b))]

Distribute:

∀x[(P(x) ∨ ¬P(a)) ∧ (¬P(b) ∨ ¬P(a)) ∧ (P(x) ∨ P(x)) ∧(P(x) ∨ ¬P(b))]

Clauses:

1) {P(x), ¬P(a)}

2) {¬P(b), ¬P(a)}

3) {P(x)}

4) {P(x), ¬P(b)}

Resolution:

5) Resolvent of clause 1 & 2, [x/b]: {¬P(a)}

6) Resolvent of clause 3 & 5, [x/a]: {}

¬F is unsatisfiable, therefore F is valid.

Comment: Absolutely correct! Need help with that?

Comment: Thanks! I'll just update my post in a couple of minutes. I will greatly appreciate it if you can check it, once I update it.

Comment: Sure, no problem!

Comment: @Bram28 I updated my post.

Comment: Yes, it's all good! (you have a $\land$ in clause 4...)

Comment: Oh my bad, that is just reckless copying and pasting. Thanks for all your help today!

Comment: Hey, you did very well just by yourself!!